# Horizontal histogram or bar plot in plt

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am not able to make a x,y histogram or bar plot (horizontal), based on the below example data. Can anyone help in this!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# data
a = [3850., 3900., 3950., 4000., 4050., 4100., 4150., 4200.]
b = [2.7000e+03, 6.9300e+04, 1.6920e+05, 2.7360e+05, 5.5620e+05,5.8950e+05, 4.5630e+05, 6.1020e+05]
df = pd.DataFrame({'altitude' : a, 'area' : b})
df

plt.hist(df.area, bins= df.altitude, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

I am expecting a such figure from this data [image]

Comment: Your `bins` are doing nothing because they are varying and not sorted. [Here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) you can find more information concerning bins: In general they are used to define the range of the ticks. Try it without: `plt.hist(df.area, orientation='horizontal')`

Comment: This is the same line I have written up, it doesn't create the expected figure. I wanted to know any correct way to get such in the above thumbnail plot.

Comment: It is not the same line, in your given code sample you can leave `bins` away so that you have `plt.hist(df.altitude, orientation='horizontal')`. If you need a specific range then you have to define bins from a sorted array as you can see in the `plt.hist` manual or in [this](https://stackabuse.com/matplotlib-histogram-plot-tutorial-and-examples/) example

Comment: Ohk, at the first it looked same, or you might have changed it or typing that time. Thank you for the suggestions. I will give it a try this way.

Comment: Your example has no value within the bins defined by you. What kind of histogram do you expect to see? Obviously, the graph is empty. However, I suspect you want to create a horizontal barplot `plt.barh(df.altitude, df.area, height=10)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this suggestion, I was looking for such figure in the end. This solves the purpose. Thank you.